# How to dump a Java class in memory to a .class file?

Tags: java, .class-file

I have a obfuscated Java jar file that decrypts itself on the fly when run in the JVM.  How can I, without an external agent, take a simple class from the JVM memory, and create a `.class` file?

I have already tried a method using a `java.lang.instrument` agent, described here: 
[Retrieving .class files from a running app](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/retrieving_class_files_from_a).

It caused the exception

```
com.sun.tools.attach.AgentInitializationException: 
    Agent JAR loaded but agent failed to initialize
    at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.loadAgent(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:121)
```

I am using JDK8.

I don't know if the `.class` file is just a serialization of the `Class` object, I guess not (it's bytecode).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, when you try to compile a java class, the result will be a .class file. for example **javac example.java** will create you a **example.class** file

Comment: no, i have a crypted jar with obfuscator, i want to dump classes from memory to disque

Comment: The code you reference is making use of the `ClassFileTransformer` interface in java.lang.instrument to grab a copy of the class's bytes as it's being loaded.  It is supported in JDK8.  It may not be supported in certain IDE environments, however, since the IDEs are jealous of their own powers.

Comment: OK, but the exception is not clear at all, how could i investigate the problem ?

Comment: Have you tried asking who you got the obfuscated jar to get you an un-obfuscated version?

Comment: If you used his recommended tool, what was your command line? Are you sure you are using the correct pid? Is this running on Linux, Windows, Mac? Are you sure JAVA_HOME is set correctly?

Comment: I run it from an eclipse project no need to use "-cp...", i am on Windows, i finally use jacoco agent its works fine, but i still wandering how it could be done by code, @Kevin Panko thank you for the editing

Answer (score -3):

```
try {
    InputStream fin = Foo.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Foo.class");
    Files.copy(fin, Paths.get("./Foo.class"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This answer is not helpful at all. You don't answer the question. What you say is how to get the class file from disk / jar / whatever and copy it. This does not help at all for in-memory decrypted classes, or classes modified by redefinition by some Java agent like PIT or JMockit.